# How to log when transfering/importing data from s3 to dynamodb using cloudformation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to cloudformation stacks and datapipilines. I am trying to import my data from s3 csv file to dynamodb, but somehow very strangely I am getting a weird error about

```
One or more parameter values are not valid. The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value. Key: user
```

In my case, I am using id as partition key and user as a sort key which are both unique and can never be empty. I checked my csv data also, there isn't any empty string for the keys either.

What I want to do is to have some logging where I can see which id is processed from s3 and successfully imported to my dynamodb. In this case I can find out where exactly the error is happening and may be know why it is happening. Not sure about it.

If you can give me some suggestion for How can I do logging, I will be thankful to you !

Thanks !

Comment: I think you're saying that you're using Data Pipeline to import a CSV file into DynamoDB and there's invalid data in the CSV. Why don't you go and validate the file content?

Comment: @jarmod , the weird thing is data is alright. There isn't any empty string in the keys, it can't be.

Comment: Data Pipeline has [logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-viewing-logs.html) options. But, note that there are [numerous CSV import options](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-bulk-csv-ingestion-to-amazon-dynamodb/). Have you tried [aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb](https://github.com/aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb)?

Comment: @jarmod I eventually know why this error is happening and trying to find answer for it. The thing is one of the entry in our database has a comma (,) in username for example username: "user,name". because of this comma in the field username, when trying to map the data from csv to dynamodb it fails. The reason is there because it is taking name after comma as a new field entry. Do you have suggestion to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you saying that the cell value is correctly quoted as `"user,name"`? I would expect a CSV parser to handle that correctly, i.e. as one value, not two. I wouldn't expect to have to escape it, like `"user\,name"`.

Comment: Yes. Somehow we have accepted this kind of username with a comma-separated. I'm not sure why, but yeah it already has happened and we can't do anything now. Do you have any example of csv parser that could be helpful here.
The data in csv file looks like below.
`1234567,"user,name",$123$,some@email.de,2002-05-28 14:07:04.0,2013-07-19 14:17:05.0,2020-02-19 15:32:18.611,2014-02-27 14:49:19.0,,,,`

Comment: The [aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb](https://github.com/aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb) option I pointed you to earlier uses Python csv DictReader and that works with your CSV content.